# Angular - How to navigate to a named router outlet in a .ts file

Tags: angular

I have a side nav and within the side nav i have named router outlet. I am trying to assign the "aside" named router outlet to a sub component called "top-words-aside". However, it cannot find the url segment.

**reports.component.html**

```
<mat-sidenav #rightsidenav position="end" fixedInViewport="fixed">
    <router-outlet name="aside"></router-outlet>
</mat-sidenav>
```

**reports.routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: ReportsComponent
    },
    {
        path: ':id',
        component: ReportDetailComponent,
        resolve: {
            job: JobResolver,
            report: ReportResolver,
            activity: ActivityResolver,
        },
        children: [
            {path: 'top-words-aside', component: TopWordsAsideComponent, outlet: 'aside'},
        ]
    }
];
```

**reports.component.ts**

```
open() {
    this.rightSideNavService.open();
    this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { aside: ['top-words-aside'] }}]);
}
```

However i get the following error.

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes.
>   URL Segment: 'top-words-aside' Error: Cannot match any routes. URL
>   Segment: 'top-words-aside'

Comment: try 
this.router.navigate(['parentHere', {outlets: {'top-words-aside':}}]);

Comment: @Stefan From my routes we can see the parent is a dynamic id.

Comment: I just tried that now it says 'ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '5a85d1cbcff47e0001e34640'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '5a85d1cbcff47e0001e34640''

Comment: this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { outletName: ['navigatingPath'] } }], { skipLocationChange: true }); what about this one

Comment: That one gives same error as original

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you import the router in your module?

you can define

> private route: ActivatedRoute

in constructor funtion.

In the open function

> this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { aside: ['top-words-aside']
>   }}],{relativeTo:this.route});

Comment: Yeah this worked. thank you. Is there a way to also pass data to this named router outlet from this.router.navigate?

Comment: you can pass data throw event ,

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: you can use Subject  next send  event ,Receive data where you need it with  Subject  subscribe。