# How can I route programmatically to a named router outlet?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, router-outlet

UPDATE: You can now try this in a minimal sample on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-k7adhd?file=src/app/components/source/source.component.ts).

The first button navigates to the route without specifying an outlet and it works.

The second button navigates to the *same* route as above, while specifying an outlet, but here, an exception is thrown implying that the route is unknown.

---

I am looking at some code for an Angular 14 application. Its main component contains, among other content, this line:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

A "button" component shown somewhere in the application has a click handler that culminates in the following instruction:

```
this.router.navigate([targetRoute]);
```

Once I click said "button", the area represented by `<router-outlet>` above is replaced with the component associated with `targetRoute`, while the other content in the main component remain visible. (`targetRoute` is a string of the form `'abc/def'`.)

So far, so good.

---

What I'd like to do now (for reasons irrelevant to this question) is, convert the router outlet into a named router outlet.

For a start, I have decided to *add* a named router outlet. Hence, I have extended the main component to contain an additional, named, router:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="contentArea" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"></router-outlet>
```

I can see this new router outlet as a blank area next to the first one, and clicking on the "button" still causes the first area to be filled with the component associated with `targetRoute`.

Now, inspired by questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44517100) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49916354), I have modified the instruction in the "button" to target the new named router outlet, all else equal (or is it?):

```
this.router.navigate([{
    outlets: {
        contentArea: [targetRoute]
    }
}]);
```

With this change, I expect the component associated with `targetRoute` to appear in the new named router outlet.

**Instead, nothing happens in the browser window and the console shows an exception:**

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'abc%2Fdef'

I have also tried passing `targetRoute` without being wrapped in an array above:

```
this.router.navigate([{
    outlets: {
        contentArea: targetRoute
    }
}]);
```

But this just yields the same error, just without URL-escaping the route:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'abc/def'

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the following to your router?

```js
{
    path: 'home',  // you can keep it empty if you do not want /home
    component: 'appComponent',
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            component: childOneComponent,
            outlet: 'child1'
        },
        {
            path: '',
            component: childTwoComponent,
            outlet: 'child2'
        }
    ]
}
```

See the following answers from [Jigar Gala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7504303/jigar-gala) / [Tomer Almog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2044706/tomer-almog)  ==>  [Angular2 multiple router-outlet in the same template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34628848/angular2-multiple-router-outlet-in-the-same-template#:%7E:text=You%20can%20have%20multiple%20router,load%20you%20are%20bootstraping%20appComponent.)

Comment: I'm not sure how to apply that to my example. Would `home` and `child1` / `child2` be my `abc` and `def`, respectively? In that case, the route is found when I do not specify the target outlet - hence I figure I must have correctly registered it (?)